# How to make javadoc.jar take priority over javadoc in sources.jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, javadoc

I have a limited selection of original source code overlayed onto decompiled code in a sources jar.

This is great as it gives me easy ability to drill down into the code when debugging however it seems to have a side effect of disabling the javadoc from the associated javadoc.jar from working in eclipse despite me having a separate javadoc.jar file with the javadoc in it.

I assume this happening because eclipse is finding the 'source code' and assumes that all the javadoc is in the source and therefore there is no need to check the javadoc.jar file.

I'd like to be able to tell eclipse (preferably using maven) to not use the sources.jar for javadoc and only use the javadoc.jar. I would still like to use the sources.jar for source code.

I have assumed that eclipse is preferring to display javadoc from sources and may be wrong so please correct me if that is the case.

Also, I may just be doing something simple the wrong way so please let me know if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I am hunting for the same thing. I have some source jars I created with jad (and since they are decompiled, they have no JavaDoc in them) and attached as source attachments. I also have the JavaDoc attached. It seems like it is a limitation of Eclipse. It will scrape the JavaDoc from the sources and display it (even if its empty) rather than looking to the JavaDoc. I wish it would notice that the JavaDoc was missing from the source and try the JavaDoc location instead. If I don't find a solution, I'm going to post the question and/or feature request over at the Eclipse site.

One workaround might be to integrate into the java decompiler (like jad) the ability to examine both the source an the javadoc, and put the javadoc back into the source. It would also then have parameter names for methods available too so it could put those back in. Lots of people have suggested this, but I cannot find anyone who has done it.

A couple of caveats. First, jad hasn't been maintained in a long time. The JD-Core/JD-Eclips website has vanished. And I have not found a better Java decompiler than jad. What happened to all the great Java decompiling gurus and solutions? Second, it might be tricky with the "align for debugging" feature to make sure the JavaDoc comments don't take up more room than is available.

Comment: No, JD-Eclipse has not vanished, it is available here : http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse and actually I switched from JAD to JD a long time ago